# Tikzgraphic displays behind text

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning

I tried to display a Tikzpicture in Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{My Figure Problem}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\section{Placeholder Text 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas = {scale=4.0}]
\draw (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Picture of a Elipse.}
\end{figure}
text continues here.
\section{Placeholder Text 2}  
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

But the Tikzpicture takes up no space and gets displayed behind the text:
[image: .]

If I replace the tikzpicture with a normal graphic, everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `transform canvas`. PGF/TikZ doesn't keep track of the bounding box then.

Comment: In my actual file, I have lots of lengths I would like to scale at once, any idea on how to replace transform canvas?

Comment: Just use `scale=0.4` directly or use the *xyz* coordinate system (the one without units) and set `x=0.4cm, y=0.4cm`. [`transform canvas`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.4) will also transform line widths. If you need nodes to be transformed, use [`transform shape`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/transform:shape).